# how to post multiple model data through one serializer in django rest api

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models, `Contact` and `User`:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    contact_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

For these two models I have two serializer classes:

```
class ContactSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('name', 'status')

class UserSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password','contact_id')
```

I want to design a serializer class which takes `name`, `username`, `password`, and `status` fields. I want to post them as key-value pairs. First `name` and `status` value saved in the `Contact` model then with `Contact` model `id` saves `username` and `password` in `User` table. How to design the serializer class in Django rest API?

Answer (score 9):

You need to override `create` method inside `UserSerializerModel`:

```
class UserSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_id = ContactSerializerModel()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
          'username',
          'password',
          'contact_id'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        contact_data = validated_data.pop('contact_id')  
        contact = Contact.objects.create(**contact_data)
        user = User.objects.create(contact_id=contact, **validated_data)
        return user
```

See details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is writeable nested serializers, and there's a section of this in the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)