# How to get data from different models in Django Rest-API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have three models, Student, Course and Homework:

What is happening is that I have a front end that the user inputs those fields in ie. all fields from `Student`, `Course` and `Homework` and once those fields are filled out they suppose to click `submit` to perform `CREATE` operation. And that's triggers the `CreatedData` function in `views.py`.

I have found some relevant examples but still, my serializer is only returning the fields from the `Student` model for `CRUD`operation. I'm not able to get the `Course` & `Homework` models fields.

[Return different serializer after create() in CreateAPIView in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439332/return-different-serializer-after-create-in-createapiview-in-django-rest-frame)

[Django Rest API. Get all data from different models in a single API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987343/django-rest-api-get-all-data-from-different-models-in-a-single-api-call)

[How to retrieve and create data from model via DJANGO REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464179/how-to-retrieve-and-create-data-from-model-via-django-rest-api)

[how to post multiple model data through one serializer in django rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050449/how-to-post-multiple-model-data-through-one-serializer-in-django-rest-api)

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,
                      primary_key=True, editable=False)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)

   

class Course(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    courseName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    courseYear = models.IntegerField(default=2021)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='courses')


class Homework(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    hwName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hwPossScore = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='homeworks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

For these three models I have three serializer classes and combined one to get all data for one API call:
**Serializers.py**

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"


class HomeworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = __all__


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
###I combine both Student and Course into one
class Combined_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    students = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    homeworks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    courses = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_students(self, obj):
        students = obj.student_set.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_homeworks(self, obj):
        homeworks = obj.homework_set.all()
        serializer = HomeworkSerializer(homeworks, many=True, read_only=True)  
        return serializer.data

    def get_courses(self, obj):
        courses = obj.courses_set.all()
        serializer = CourseSerializer(courses, many=True, read_only=True)  
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id','firstName','age','homeworks','courses')
```

**views.py**

```
 class CreatedData(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     queryset = Student.objects.all()

     serializer_class = Combined_Serializer


    def create(self, request, pk=None):
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data) 
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       self.perform_create(serializer)
       headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
       student_id  = serializer.data['student_id']
       name = serializer.data['Name']        
       student_age = serializer.data['age'] 
       print("SERIALIZER.DATA >" , serializer.data)
       print("HEADERS", headers)
```

I'm not able to see the `Course` & `Homework` models fields when I print `serializer.data`, only fields from `Student` models I can get the fields.

I want to design a view which I can access the all fields from all tables. I want to get them after user click `submit` button.

How to design the view to get that other information in Django rest API?

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Its because in combined serializer you have used model serializer which only saved student related data although you provided other data as well

Comment: @ShishirSubedi there are other fields as well in Combined_Serializer

Comment: yeah but since you have used model serializer and in class meta you specify model student; that's why on serializer save method only save student model.

Comment: @ShishirSubedi You cannot use serializer class without meta.

Comment: Try inheriting from serializers.Serializer instead of ModelSerializer and write your own create method in serializer class

Comment: ok, could you send some snipped how to do this? thats why Im asking here;) dont know how to implement it? and do you have good youtube channel for rest-api development?

Comment: okay I'm posting code snippet, but I'm not sure will work or not; but definetely give you some idea.

Comment: Can you give brief description about what you are trying to do. I think model you have designed seems incorrect. Like Course have student_id as foreign key and students as many field. If the course model is supposed to store the record of student enrolled in particular course then it would be better to only include students many field or create a new course model with name and in another StudentCourse model attach student id and course id.

Comment: models are just fake. just focus how you save them and get them.

Answer (score 1):

`Combined_Serializer` returns only the student fields because:

- model setting: in `Meta`,  `model = Student`
- relation:  `students = obj.student_set.all()` <- can you explain how this relation works?

If you *have to* specify model in the serializer, you can create an abstract model that has foreign key relation to all three models - Student, Course, Homework and modify your serializer accordingly. But it's recommended only if the class will have a solid use and a single responsibility.

````py
class StudentCourseHomework: 
    
```you can name it better with abstract term that explains 
what you want to do with this model```

    student = models.ForeignKey()
    course = models.ForeignKey()
    homework = models.ForeignKey()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
````

#### Alternatives

You can create serializer without model using `serializers.Serializer`.

```py
class CombinedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = StudentSerializer.Meta.fields
        + CoursetSerializer.Meta.fields
        + HomeworkSerializer.Meta.fields
```

#### Other things

- removing underscore in class name will be more clean.
- if you really intend to make serializer that has all three models' fields, it might be better to use a more specific name.
- Or you can use the view class name like `CreateDataSerializer`

Comment: i hope this helps. if you are looking for different approach or have more questions, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

```
class CombinedCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    students = NewStudentSerializer()
    homeworks = NewHomeworkSerializer() # with minimal fields required to create like student_id is not required as it will be obtained later
    courses = NewCourseSerializer() # with minimal fields

    def create(self, validated_data):
        student = Student.objects.create(**validated_data['students'])
        # add student id in courses data
        courses = Course.objects.create(**validated_data['courses'])
        # add student id and course id in homeworks data
        homeworks = Homework.objects.create(**validated_data['homework'])
        return student
```

In views

```
class CreatedData(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Combined_Serializer # your previously defined

    def create(self, request):
       # first verify combined create serializer
       combined_create_serializer = CombinedCreateSerializer(data=request.data) 
       combined_create_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       student_instance = self.perform_create(combined_create_serializer)
       combined_serializer_data = self.get_serializer(student_instance) # your final data here which is from previously defined
       # ... rest of your codes
```

In the past I have achieved doing similar like this; good luck